# Check if password protected post is visible

Tags: theme-development, templates, password, template-tags

Is there anyway of checking if a password protected post is visible / not visible? I want some thing that says this;

If the post is password protected (that parts fine) and the correct password hasn't been entered, then show 'XXX', else show 'ZZZ'.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`post_password_required()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/post_password_required): whether post requires password and correct password has been provided.

```
<?php
if ( post_password_required() ) {
     echo 'xxx';
} else {
     echo 'zzz';
}
```